# victory-native victoryAxis not rendered the last y axis value, React native

Tags: react-native, expo, victory-native

I have data more than 12 x and y values, When I get 13 values it will having unrendered.

the output page 1 looks like

[image]

at the end the data is unrendered,

code reproduce.
https://snack.expo.io/@mrvictoria/victory-native

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Anyway I solve the problem for future reference I will write the correct answer,
I just need to recheck the victory-native [docs](https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/docs/victory-bar)

code looks like this

```
<VictoryChart
width={1000}
theme={Theme}

labelComponent={<VictoryTooltip renderInPortal={false} />}
domainPadding={{ x: 25 }}
domainPadding={25}>
{/* Horizontal */}
<VictoryAxis
    responsive={false}
    style={{
        ticks: {
            // padding: 12,
        },
        tickLabels: {
            fontSize: 13,
        },
    }}
/>
{/* Vertical */}
<VictoryAxis
    dependentAxis

/>
<VictoryBar
    style={{
        ticks: {
            // padding: 12,
        },
        tickLabels: {
            fontSize: 13,
        },
    }}
    // labelComponent={
    //     <VictoryTooltip
    //         flyoutStyle={{ stroke: "tomato", strokeWidth: 2 }}
    //     />}
    categories={{
        x: [
    "10-06",
    "10-07",
    "10-08",
    "10-09",
    "10-12",
    "10-13",
    "10-14",
    "10-15",
    "10-16",
    "10-19",
    "10-20",
    "10-21"
]
    }}
    data={[
    {
        "x": 1,
        "y": 13
    },
    {
        "x": 2,
        "y": 12
    },
    {
        "x": 3,
        "y": 13
    },
    {
        "x": 4,
        "y": 12
    },
    {
        "x": 5,
        "y": 34
    },
    {
        "x": 6,
        "y": 12
    },
    {
        "x": 7,
        "y": 12
    },
    {
        "x": 8,
        "y": 14
    },
    {
        "x": 9,
        "y": 8
    },
    {
        "x": 10,
        "y": 39
    },
    {
        "x": 11,
        "y": 14
    },
    {
        "x": 12,
        "y": 14
    }
]}
    style={{
        data: { fill: colors.PRIMARY_COLOR_GPA, width: 30 },
        parent: { border: '1px solid #ccc' },
    }}
/>
```